# Bibtex not capitalizing month in ieeetr format

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, formatting

The correct format to display months in `IEEEtr` format is capitalize the first letter followed by two letters and a dot (e.g. `Apr.`). However, I obtain only `apr`. A minimum example is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\begin{document}

\cite{Gustafsson2005}

\clearpage % Force Bibliography to the end of document on a new page
\bibliography{zubairy}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

\end{document}
```

However, compiling with `xelatex` and `bibtex`, I get:

[1] M. G. L. Gustafsson, “Nonlinear structured-illumination microscopy:
wide-field fluorescence imaging with theoretically unlimited resolution.,”
*Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences*, vol. 102, pp. 13081–13086, `sep 2005`.

Jabref generated bibtex entry is:

```
  @Article{Gustafsson2005,
  author       = {M. G. L. Gustafsson},
  title        = {{Nonlinear structured-illumination microscopy: wide-field fluorescence imaging with theoretically unlimited resolution.}},
  journal      = {Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
  year         = {2005},
  volume       = {102},
  number       = {37},
  pages        = {13081--13086},
  month        = {sep},
  issn         = {0027-8424},
  date         = {2005-09},
  doi          = {10.1073/pnas.0406877102},
  pmid         = {16141335},
  publisher    = {Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
}
```

How do I make it appear correctly, i.e., `Sep.`?

Comment: It turns out that removing the braces around the month entry, `month        = sep,` works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because OP solved the question himself as stated in the comments.

Comment: Although it capitalizes the first letter, it comes out as `Sept.`, which is still incorrect.

Comment: @cfr Yes, you're right it's not really a quirk. I'll delete the comment. I was mainly trying to stop the close effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The month should not be in curly brackets. This is standard BibTeX as far as I know. If it is in curly brackets, it is a regular value. If it is not in curly brackets, it is a string and will be replaced with the relevant value. This is expected.

As you point out, this is not sufficient because the substituted value will be incorrect. This is because `Sep.` is not a standard abbreviation for September, but `Sept.` is. In order to use IEEEtrans's idiosyncratic abbreviations, load their `.bib` file.

Simply following the documentation seems to work.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Gustafsson2005,
  author       = {M. G. L. Gustafsson},
  title        = {{Nonlinear structured-illumination microscopy: wide-field fluorescence imaging with theoretically unlimited resolution.}},
  journal      = {Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
  year         = {2005},
  volume       = {102},
  number       = {37},
  pages        = {13081--13086},
  month        = sep,
  issn         = {0027-8424},
  date         = {2005-09},
  doi          = {10.1073/pnas.0406877102},
  pmid         = {16141335},
  publisher    = {Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\begin{document}

\cite{Gustafsson2005}

\clearpage % Force Bibliography to the end of document on a new page
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\end{document}
```

[image: September the IEEEtran way]

Comment: Thanks for sorting it out. As a side, why would places like doi2bib.org and jabref generate entries with month inside braces?

Comment: @HasanTahirAbbas No idea, sorry. They shouldn't.